# Are long properties name in cosmos can increase size of storage?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to know that properties with long name can increase size of storage in cosmos db? or use small name like **fn** instead of  **FiratName** can reduce size of storage?
I can't found any document about it.

Any body can help me...
thanks.

Comment: The [Maximum size of an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-item-limits) is based on the UTF-8 length of JSON representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know that properties with long name can increase size of
> storage in cosmos db?

Yes, the length of the property name count towards the total size of the document. Using small names instead of full name will definitely help towards reducing the storage size.

Comment: thanks @gaurav-mantri .do you have any paper or link about this for more information?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to find it right away. However I saw an answer from [Mark Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884931/mark-brown) (he's part of Cosmos DB team) regarding this some time back. You may want to browse through his answers.